# view pending status data in table by default

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-select

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectrequest" ng-model="selectedrequest">

                        <option value="pending" > Pending </option>
                        <option value="approved"> Approved </option>
                        <option value="rejected"> Rejected </option>
                    </select>


<tr ng-repeat="mymodel in vm.modelname  | filter:selectedrequest">
                        <td>{{mymodel.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{mymodel.triggername}}</td>
                        <td>{{mymodel.status}}<td>
                    </tr>

vm.modelname=[{
    name:'Peter',
    triggername:'Peter1',
    status:pending
},{
    name:'Jack',
    trigger name:'Jack Hein',
    status:approved
}]
```

Prob stint: by default pending status is selected and corresponding data is populated. let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: Not clear both what the problem is and what the desired result might be. Please clarify.

Comment: There is dropdown if i select approved as status, the corresponding data should populate the table. Works fine till here. but the prob is the approved status should be "by default" selected and data should be populated in table.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wLd182gx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable using $scope as:

```
$scope.selected_request = "Pending";
```

With this by default your intended data is selected.

Comment: What exactly your requirement and what going wrong?

Comment: hope u get the issue.

Comment: Let me know what is the problem?

Comment: as of now by default selection is all i.e. no selection. It should

Comment: as of now by default selection is all i.e. no selection. It should be selected by default pending .

Comment: You mean under select list, there should be no item unless selected.

Comment: Select list should be by default "Pending". and correspond data in table below.

Comment: yes. one more solution can be  if we initialize like this ng-init="selectedrequest='pending'"

Comment: yes. one more solution can be  if we initialize like this ng-init="selectedrequest='pending'" from the view side itself. simple. Thanks a lot Sai.

Comment: Yes. But, don't use `ng-init` more often as it reduces performance. Better use it in controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please made changes in your select tag like below. It will make "approved" selected by default and also populate your table according to selection.
Hope it will help.

```
   <body>
      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>

      <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
        <select class="form-control" id="selectrequest" ng-init="selected_request='approved';selected_requested()" ng-model="selected_request" ng-change="selected_requested()">

          <option value="Pending"> Pending </option>
          <option value="approved" > Approved </option>
          <option value="rejected"> Rejected </option>
        </select>
        <div ng-repeat="temp in model | filter:(!!selected_request || undefined) && {status: selected_request} ">
          <span ng-bind="temp.name">
                 </span>
        </div>
        <br/> Items in filtered Array
        <br/>
        <div ng-repeat="temp in filteredArray">
          <span ng-bind="temp.name">
                 </span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>
```